# How do I do custom key binding in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, keyboard, applescript

How would I assign

- ⌘1 to Music (Library item)
- ⌘2 to Movies
- ⌘3 to Podcasts

Surprisingly enough, these key bindings are not assigned to anything yet, and IMO they would be most convenient ones (see e.g. Mail.app).

I can't see any relevant item in AppleScript dictionary for iTunes…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each Source/Library item (Music,Movies,Podcasts) you want to open with a shortcut, create a new Applescript as follows

```
tell application "iTunes"
try
    set view of front browser window to (get some playlist whose special kind is Podcasts)
end try
end tell
```

replacing "Podcasts" with "Music” or "Movies", and save it with to your ~/Library/iTunes/Scripts folder (if this doesn´t exist, create it!), giving it an unique name (like "show podcasts","show movies").

Next, open "System Preferences">"Keybaord">"Keyboard Shortcuts" and select "Application Shortcuts". Click on the little "plus" button to add a new shortcut with:

```
Application: iTunes
Menu Title: show podcasts   —this has to be exactly the name you gave your script
Keyboard Shortcut: <press your desired shortcut, eg. "cmd+2">
```

Now pressing "cmd+2" (or whichever shortcut you defined) while being in iTunes will open the Podcast library item.

Comment: Genius :-) That's exactly what I was hoping to achieve.

Comment: Do you know any workaround for "Apps" item (special kind (none/Books/folder/Genius/iTunes U/Library/Movies/Music/Party Shuffle/Podcasts/Purchased Music/TV Shows, r/o) : special playlist kind)?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. And if i select Apps/Ringtones and try to get their name/id, nothing returns. :-(

Answer (score -1):

Try going into Settings → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts tab → Application Shortcuts in the left panel.

There you can add a custom shortcut to any specific application menu item. Just add itunes to the list and add your shortcut.

Comment: There are no such items in iTunes' menu.

Comment: @piobyz It's not the menu in iTunes. It's the global settings on your Mac.

Comment: This does not work here, as there are no menu items in iTunes to select sources that then could be triggered from "System Preferences">"Keybaord">"Keyboard Shortcuts"